# Writing sheet music on your smartphone

Tags: notation, sheet-music, software

This is my first question so sorry if its a poor one for this style of forum.

I regularly write and sight-read standard notation but there are plenty of times im caught without pen and paper or a computer. When that happens I usually just record the idea on my phone using my voice if at all possible. However, if im on a plane, for example, that's not practical. So my question is:

Is there any good android applications that allow you to write your own sheet music?...Preferably with audio playback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if this fits all the criteria you are looking for, but there is [**NotateMe**](http://www.neuratron.com/notateme.html) which is available on Google Play and App Store. It allows you to write music sheets with your finger (or a pen) and is 'translated' into sheet music.

Here is a video demonstration:

---

There is also [**Ensemble Composer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lotuz.musiccomposer&hl=en).

---

And there is [**Maestro**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.revelli.maestro&hl=en)

---

And there is [**Music Notation**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.philblandford.passacaglia&hl=en)

Answer (score 4):

I just found out there's also a smartphone version of Guitar Pro. That might especially be of interest to all you tabbers out there who are unable to sight-read standard notation. [GuitarPro](http://guitar-pro.com)